# Multiple custom UITableView cells and sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm trying to create this look:

[image]

Right now I have this:

[image]

Three prototype cells with identifiers and custom cells respectively from top to bottom as

ID

- cellStyle
- cellStyle2
- cellStyle3

with the custom cell classes merely having a capital C.

This is my code so far:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to change the dequeue cell to my different custom cell classes to be able to access their properties and change the labels and UIImageView.  This method is not working `cell.label.text` is not recognized.  I also tried creating three different variables for cell like so.

```
var cellStyle: CellStyle
var cellStyle2: CellStyle2
var cellStyle3: CellStyle3
```

What do I `return` for the function then?

Questions:

1. Are either methods standard practice? If not, what is the standard code to accomplish what I'm trying to do?
2. To get the cells to look like the top three buttons on my prototype do I need to inset?  I already have this in the runtime

`layer.borderColor
layer.borderWidth
layer.cornerRadius
layer.masksToBounds`

3. How do you configure `numberOfRowsInSection` for multiple sections?

This is an update to my previous code based on comments.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        switch indexPath.row {

        case 0:

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellStyle", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellStyle

            cell.label?.text = "Friends"
            // Configure cell

        case 1:

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellStyle2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellStyle2

            // Configure cell
            cell.label?.text = "Random"


        case 2:

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellStyle", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellStyle

            // Configure cell
            cell.label?.text = "Judge"


        default:
            // Default cell with no text

            cell.textLabel?.text = ""

        }

        switch indexPath.section {

        case 0:
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellStyle3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!  cellStyle3

            // Configure cell

            cell.label?.text = "" // TODO: Need to put name from opponent _User reference into here
//             cell.friendProfilePic.image = //Query facebook api for profile picture of friend with Facebook ID for "opponent"


        case 1:
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellStyle3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellStyle3

            // Configure cell
            cell.label?.text = "" // TODO: Need to put name from opponent _User reference into here
            //             cell.friendProfilePic.image = //Query facebook api for profile picture of friend with Facebook ID for "opponent"


        case 2:
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellStyle3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellStyle3

            // Configure cell
            cell.label?.text = "" // TODO: Need to put name from opponent _User reference into here
            //             cell.friendProfilePic.image = //Query facebook api for profile picture of friend with Facebook ID for "opponent"


        default:
            // Default cell with no text

            cell.textLabel?.text = ""

        }


        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You better paste actual code than snapshot of it.

Comment: You have declared `cell` as `UITableViewCell` so even though you are dequeueing custom cells the compiler won't know about the subclass properties.  You need to dequeue into a variable of the right type (or simply let the compiler infer the type) and then return this value from the method.  Normally I will have a single `return cell` at the end of the method and assign the relevant custom cell to that after I have dequeued and configured it.

Comment: I don't understand your third question. You need to return the correct number of rows for each section.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is this the method that you're talking about?  I named the different custom cells `cell` then I was able to access their properties.  In regards to the third question, I think I figured it out?  I'm just going to `.count` the array for data coming from Parse for the different sections.

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to return `cell` because you are declaring it inside the case statements, and in the case of your default you don't allocate a cell at all. You need to declare `cell` outside the switch, retrieve the cell into another variable of the right type and thenassignnthat variable to cell so you can return it or have multiple return statements,,one in each case

Comment: So you're saying I can just do this.  `case 0:
            
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellStyle", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellStyle
            
            cell.label?.text = "Friends"
            // Configure cell
            return cell`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?